# Excel data connection to SQL dB error

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, database-connection

I crafted a macro in an Excel workbook to extract a subset of data from a SQL database based on user input.

The macro prompts the user for a parameter input and inserts that parameter into a ready-made stored procedure configured into a an Excel data connection - see below for my vba:

```
  Sub RefreshDBQuery()

  Dim Val As Integer

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Worksheets("Adjustable CF").Select
  Val = InputBox("Enter valid 4 digit number", , 1907)

  Sheets("TestData").Visible = True

  Worksheets("TestData").Select
  Worksheets("TestData").Range("A1").Select

  ActiveCell.Value = Val

  With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("MacroExtraction 2Server").OLEDBConnection

    .CommandText = "EXEC dbo.prV_FlowExtract '" &      Range("A1").Value & "'"

  End With

  ActiveWorkbook.Connections("MacroExtraction 2Server").Refresh

  Sheets("TestData").Visible = False

  End Sub
```

When I run it - it works fine and additionally, since it's modifying an existing data connection ( the one I previously configured), I notice a odc file in a folder called "My Data Sources" under My Documents:

[image: snapshot of the odc file residing locally on my desktop Documents folder]

However, when I send this workbook over to a colleague to run the macro and to extract data - the macro is able to run up to a point, and she receives an error:
[image: SQL state 42000, Server error 4060]

I ask her to open up the folder "My Data Sources" and I don't see an odc file:
[image: no 'MacroExtraction 2Server' odc]

My question is: what am I missing? Or rather what is my colleague missing in order to get her macro to work on her local machine?

I checked with the dB administrator who said that she has the permissions necessary to access the server, so that's why I am picking on the lack of the odc as a cause for my concern. Should I copy my odc file and send it to her to copy into her Data Sources folder? Should I rewrite the macro and re-setup the data connection on her local machine? Anyone with experience to comment would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: So what you are missing here is that data connections are specific to your PC. In your code you are opening that connection string and refreshing it but that oledb connection string is still housed on  your PC in your or "My Data Sources". It depends on your intent and how access is set up for the server as to how you would go about adjusting your code and if you would adjust it at all.

Answer (score 0):

The macro alone does not contain all the necessary info (server name, for example?). Try running "NewSQLServerConnection.odc" in you colleague's my data sources location, complete the necessary data, make sure the connection name is the same as in your macro, and then the macro should work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: PS - if it still doesn't work after that and you use windows authentication in your database connection, try logging on to your colleague's computer and see if it works. If it does, you should chat to your DBA again :)

Comment: Did you mean `MacroExtraction 2Server.odc` in my colleague's data sources folder? Will do - will see if that works. Thanks!

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Keep me posted!

Comment: Try to not just copy the file but configure it by accessing newsqlserverconnection.odc